# Rails deleting a returned relation from subtraction of two queries

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, database-relations

I have three models

```
class Account
  has_many :link_requests, :through => :suppliers 
end

class Supplier
  has_many :link_requests, :dependent => :destroy
end

class LinkRequest
  belongs_to :supplier
  belongs_to :account
end
```

I have it so that suppliers can be inputted individually or in bulk through excel.

When a supplier is deleted individually it will remove all the link_requests that belong to it. But we have a method to delete all the suppliers in bulk through a SQL query. But all the link_requests are left behind. I have updated the query now so that it will handle this exception but now we end up with a whole bunch of dead data.

This is really the only way i can figure out how to find the 'dead data'.

`LinkRequest.where(account_id: current_account)` 
will return all the link_requests belonging to the current_account, those that have deleted suppliers and ones with existing suppliers, as a  `ActiveRecord::Relation`.

Then i can call: `current_account.link_requests` which will return all link_requests with existing suppliers, also as a `=> ActiveRecord::Relation`

There is no attribute that the `link_request` has that can separate ones with existing suppliers and ones with deleted suppliers. So i can't just call all invalid ones, the only way i know they are valid is because current_account gets its link_requests through its existing suppliers.

So my initial thought was to subtract all the valid ones from the sum total of all the link_requests that way i would be left with all the 'invalid requests' and call destroy_all on them.

Only when i subtract the two relations i get an Array.

```
LinkRequest.where(account_id: current_account).count
  => 10
current_account.link_requests.count 
  => 4

(LinkRequest.where(acconut_id: current_account) - current_acconut.link_requests).count
  => 6  #these are all the invalid ones.

dead_links = (LinkRequest.where(acconut_id: current_account) - current_acconut.link_requests)
dead_links.class
  => Array
```

There is no way i can then call destroy_all on an array since in has no relation to the suppliers db anymore. i get `!! #<NoMethodError: undefined method 'destroy_all' for #<Array:0x007fdb59a67728>>`

To compare every link_requests supplier_id with the existing suppliers DB and then delete ones that don't match will be a very expensive operation, since the DB has hundreds of millions of both data types. so i was thinking of creating a before filter on the LinkRequests controller that will delete them for its current account when he runs the indexing action.

```
  private
    def clean_up_boogle_link_requests
      @dead_requests = LinkRequest.where(account_id: current_account) - current_account.manual_boogle_link_requests
      @dead_requests.delete_all if !dead_requests.empty?
    end
```

something like this.. any other ideas will be much appreciated, i am hoping to find a way to get a relation object back after comparing the two query's and then be able to act on that.

Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will do the trick:

```
dead_link_ids = LinkRequest.where(acconut_id: current_account).pluck(:id) -
  current_acconut.link_requests.pluck(:id)
LinkRequest.where(id: dead_link_ids).delete_all
```

Comment: Thank you kind sir. its so simple now that its in front of me.